# Assistance with understanding complicated REGEX string

Tags: regex

We are currently looking into migrating python 2 code to python 3.
In the code we are looking at there is a regex being done and for the life of me I can't figure out what the regex string means. I'm hoping that there someone out there that can help me decypher the regex string.
Here's the code snippet

```py
String findString ="(?<=((?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\){0,500}))\\\\\"";
String replaceString = "\"\"";
try {
....
      p.apply(Regex.replaceAll(findString, replaceString))
....

} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    throw e;
  }
....
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is python code?

Comment: have you tried pasting it into regex101.com?